# How to populate new column with function output on existing column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a datafrom where one of the columns is a First Name. I would like to pass the first name through the [gender-guesser](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gender-guesser) library to get the best guess of the name's gender. However, when I attempt to create a new 'Gender' column and pass the data from the 'First Name' column with:

```
df_names['Gender'] = gender.Detector().get_gender(df_names['First Name'])
```

I get the error

```
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

I think it has something to do with what the gender guesser is doing under the hood, but I'm not 100% sure.  I get tracebacks to both the gender-guesser and pandas. I am able to pass strings to the guesser and get a return without issue. I am also able to write my own super simple function to concatenate the 'First Name' data with another string and get a valid output; like:

```
def concat(x):
    return x+" something more"

df_names['More'] = concat(df_names['First Name'])
```

And that works as expected as well; creating a new column with the matching contents.

I am also able to get a single, correct, return using iloc. I have been able to get a for loop to work, but it takes too long to be practical.

Comment: `df_names['Gender'] = df_names['First Name'].apply(lambda x: gender.Detector().get_gender(x))`

Comment: This does give me result I'm hoping for, but it doesn't seem to be any faster than iterating through with a for loop using iloc[i].

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're running into an implementation detail of the `get_gender` method, it is most likely trying to use the `First Name` as the key to a dictionary, which would cause python to call the `first name` object's `__hash__` method and throw the error (which you can see [in the code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/2522efa9e687e777d966f49af70b325922699bea/pandas/core/generic.py#L894)).

As you've already observed with your `concat` method, the key to getting around this might be just to cast the `first name` object to a string:

```
df_names['Gender'] = gender.Detector().get_gender(
    str(df_names['First Name']) # make First Name a generic str instance
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Jaymon! This does get ride of the error, and everything runs without complaint.  However, 'unknown' is the only result that is returned.  I have previously tried casting with `df_names['First Name'].str` with the same 'unknown' result.  `print (df_names['First Name'].str)` shows that it is sending `<pandas.core.strings.StringMethods object at 0x11f0de1d0>` into `get_gender` with that.  I'm wondering if the way you mentioned isn't doing something similar.  Though printing your suggestion does return a human readable output.

Comment: Hrm, it seems `unknown` is returned when `gender.Detector().names` [doesn't contain the name](https://github.com/lead-ratings/gender-guesser/blob/master/gender_guesser/detector.py#L88), so I would make sure that it is getting populated with something and go from there

Answer (score 0):

Never used gender detector but I'm guessing this should work

```
gd = gender.Detector()
df_names['Gender'] = df_names['First Name'].apply(gd.get_gender)
```